# PHP form not updating mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

Here's the code:

HTML:

```
  <div class="modal-body">
  <input type="text" name="tradelink" class="tradeurlinput" id="tradeurlinput">
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
  <button class="savechanges" id="savechanges" type="submit" name="SubmitTlink" value="update" >Save Changes</button>
  </div>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","") or die("Connection Failed");
$db_found = mysqli_select_db($con, 'tutorial') or die("connection failed");

if (isset($_POST['SubmitTlink'])) {
    $tradelink = $_POST['tradelink'];
    $result = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE tlink SET tlink= '$tradelink' WHERE steamid = '".$steamprofile['steamid']."'");
    if (mysqli_query($result)) {
        echo "updated";
        mysqli_close($con);
    } else {
        echo "fail";}
        mysqli_close($con);
    }
}
?>
```

I've tried to fix this by myself but i just can't get it to work, suggestions?

Comment: `UPDATE tlink SET tlink` Whaaat? Can you share your table structure please? Along with DML and DDL. Also show your full code.

Comment: where is the <form> tag ?

Comment: @BipinKareparambil Would be in the rest of the code.

Comment: Which error is returned to you?

Comment: details of $steamprofile['steamid']? and form tag?

Comment: You are using mysqli_query() twice. once for the sql statement and then querying executed query result

Comment: and also please come up with any error if received.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is here:

```
  // Some more code.
  if(mysqli_query($result)) { // You should check the truthiness of this.
    echo "updated";
    mysqli_close($con);       // You don't need this here.
  }
  else{
    echo "fail";
  }
  mysqli_close($con);         // This is optional, but fine.
}
```

The `$result` is an update query, which will have only `true` or `false` returned. So doing `mysqli_query(true)` makes no sense, plus it throws an error saying that it is expecting a MySQLi Connection Object as the first parameter and not a boolean value.

So changing your code, you should have...

```
  // Some more code.
  if($result) {
    echo "updated";
  }
  else {
    echo "fail";
  }
  mysqli_close($con);         // This is optional, but fine.
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, still it dind't work, it doesnt echo "fail" or "updated" to begin with

Comment: No, when i click the button nothing happens, and there are no errors displayed

Answer (score 0):

```
No need of use mysqli_query twice.Try this code  


    <?php
        $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","") or die("Connection Failed");
        $db_found = mysqli_select_db($con, 'tutorial') or die("connection failed"); 
        if(isset($_POST['SubmitTlink'])){
        $tradelink = $_POST['tradelink'];    
        $result = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE tlink SET tlink= '$tradelink' WHERE steamid = '".$steamprofile['steamid']."'");
         if(($result)){
        echo "updated";
        mysqli_close($con);
         }
        else{
        echo "fail";}
        mysqli_close($con);
        }

        ?>
```

Comment: Well, Shanu, that's the same thing I have written... `;)`

Answer (score 0):

One of the things I noticed is that you don't have a form with a medthod and action, there for your code should look like

```
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
   <div class="modal-body">
      <input type="text" name="tradelink" class="tradeurlinput" id="tradeurlinput">
   </div>
   <div class="modal-footer">
      <button class="savechanges" id="savechanges" type="submit" name="SubmitTlink" value="update" >Save Changes</button>
   </div>
</form>
```

Then when the button is clicked you need to check if the field tradelink is set and not empty, then you can start the update when that is true, and try to use mysqli prepared statements all the time, you need to google that why is it important to use prepared statements.

> NB: Always validate,filter, and sanitize user inputs, treat each input
>   from a user as if its from a very dangerous hacker.

Your php script should look something like this.

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die("Connection Failed");
$db_found = mysqli_select_db($con, 'tutorial') or die("connection failed");

if (isset($_POST['SubmitTlink'])) {

        if (empty($_POST['tradelink'])) {

                die("enter tradelink");
        } else {

                $tradelink = $_POST['tradelink'];

                $sql = $con->prepare("UPDATE tlink SET tlink =? where steamid = ?");
                $sql->bind_param('si', $tradelink, $steamprofile);

                if ($sql->execute()) {

                        echo "update";
                } else {

                        echo "fail" . mysqli_error();
                }

                $sql->close();
                $con->close();
        }
}
?>
```

Hope this helps and solves the issue,

PS: You can connect and select database in one line.

```
$con = new mysqli("host", "user, "password, DB);
```

I'm open to suggessions incase I miss something, thanks.